# jQuery requires a window with a document in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, reactjs.net

I'm using ReactJS.net (server-side render) and when I use jquery in Webpack then I got error
here is my error

> Error while rendering "Components.ToDoListSkeleton" to
>   "react_0LmYYfSk30qdrKJQe4McUQ": Error: jQuery requires a window with a
>   document
>       at module.exports (Script Document [5]:51:87) -> module.exports=global.document?factory(global,true):function(w){if(!w.document){throw
>   new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");}return
>   factory(w);};}else {factory(global);} // Pass this if window is not
>   defined yet
>       at new ToDoListSkeleton (Script Document [5]:26:903)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._constructComponentWithoutOwner (Script Document [2]:8271:28)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._constructComponent (Script Document [2]:8253:22)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (Script Document [2]:8172:22)
>       at ReactReconciler.mountComponent (Script Document [2]:1977:36)
>       at Script Document [2]:19549:37
>       at Mixin.perform (Script Document [2]:3788:21)
>       at renderToStringImpl (Script Document [2]:19544:25)
>       at renderToString (Script Document [2]:19574:11)
>       at Script Document [7] [temp]:1:16 Line: 19549 Column:37

here is my webpack config

```
"use strict";

var path = require('path');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'Content'),
    entry: {
        server: './server'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Transform JSX in .jsx files
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' },
            { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        // Allow require('./blah') to require blah.jsx
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    externals: {
        //// Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
        //// bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
        react: "React"
    },
    plugins: [
      new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery", 
          jQuery: "jquery", 
          "window.jQuery": "jquery",    
      })
    ]
};
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jQuery is only designed for use in a browser, and does **not** support server-side rendering. You'll need to remove jQuery from any of your code that you want to use server-side.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but could you show me how to bundle libs by webpack, my scenario is that I have many of external libs such as bootraps, jQuery, moment js and I don't want put it in the script <script> tag, I just want to "require(lib-name)" my external libs if I need it. Thanks :D

Comment: this isn't true. There's a `jsdom` package which can be used for server-side rendering.

Comment: @maxple - Sure, but what parts of jQuery do you actually need if you want to do server-side rendering? jsdom is a pretty heavy dependency, you'd be better off rewriting your code such that it's not coupled to jQuery.

Comment: One would require jsdom so that they could use jquery to manipulate documents on a server. Im not really sure what you mean by it being a heavy dependency. What do you mean when you say It should not be tied to jquery? Like writing plain js instead?